# Windows Application hosting Windows AZURE Cloud service provided by Microsoft

Tags: windows, azure, cloud

Is it possible to host a Windows Application to be hosted in Windows Azure cloud service provided by Mircrosoft.

Comment: Yes it is possible. But what do you really intend to accomplish?

Comment: Our application basically uploads data into database and then other part of the application will take that data and send it to the hardware (which is connected to the PC throug USB Ports). So, will even this kind of applications are well suited for WINDOWS AZURE compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure is best suited for hosting either web facing applications (i.e. web sites) or data processing applications (like traditional Windows Services).  Desktop Windows applications that require user interaction would not be a good fit for Windows Azure.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that Windows Applications cant be hosted OR it can be hosted provided with few changes done to the applications which makes it Web Compliant.